# Ошибка при перерисовке линий (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition, дерево

Код:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEBKOY

```js
var gId = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('circle').live('click', function(){
        var svg = d3.select('svg');
        var el = d3.select("g[data-id='"+$(this).data('id')+"']");
        addChildren($(this), el);
    });

    $('circle').live('mousedown', function(event) {
        if (event.which === 3)  {
           delAll($(this));
        }

    });
});

// Функция добавления нового элемента
function addChildren(parent, el){
    var row = parent.data('row')+1;
    var cy = parseInt(parent.attr('cy'))+50;
    el.append("circle")
        .attr("data-row", row)
        .attr("r", "16")
        .attr("cx", "50%")
        .attr("cy", cy)
        .attr("data-id", ++gId);
    el.append("text")
        .attr("x", "50%")
        .attr("y", cy+5)
        .attr("data-row", row)
        .attr("data-id", gId);
    el.append("line")
        .attr("data-row", row)
        .attr("x1", parent.attr('cx'))
        .attr("y1", parseInt(parent.attr('cy'))+8)
        .attr("x2", "50%")
        .attr("y2",  cy-8)
        .attr("data-id", gId);
    el.append("g").attr("data-id", gId);

    recalcX(row);
    numbering();
}

// Функция пересчета координат
function recalcX(row){
    var count = $('circle[data-row='+row+']').length; // Количество элементов в строке
    var a = 100/(count+1);
    var b = 0;
    $('circle[data-row='+row+']').each(function(){
        b+=a;
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("cx", b+'%');
        var id = d3.select(this).attr('data-id');
        $('g[data-id='+id+'] > line').each(function(){ // Пересчет линий, которые НИЖЕ данной строки
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("x1", b+'%');
        });
    });

    b = 0;

    $('line[data-row='+row+']').each(function(){  // Пересчет координат линий
        b+=a;
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("x2", b+'%');
    });

    b = 0;

    $('text[data-row='+row+']').each(function(){  // Пересчет координат текста
        b+=a;
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("x", b-1.5+'%');
    });
}

// Функция нумерации
function numbering(svg){
    d3.selectAll('svg text').text(function(d,i){return i+1});
}

// Функция удаления без сохранения связей
function delAll(element){
    var id = element.data('id');
    var row = element.data('row');
    d3.select('circle[data-id="'+id+'"]').remove();
    d3.select('line[data-id="'+id+'"]').remove();
    d3.select('text[data-id="'+id+'"]').remove();
    d3.select('g[data-id="'+id+'"]').remove();


    while ($('circle[data-row="' + row + '"]').length > 0) {
        recalcX(row);
        row++;
    }

}
```

```css
 svg{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        line{
            stroke: black;
        }
        text{
            fill: white;
        }
        circle{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="500"  >
    <circle data-row="1" r="16" cx="50%" cy="20" data-id="1"></circle>
    <text x="49%" y="25">1</text>
    <g data-id="1"></g> 
</svg>
</body>
```

Нажатие левой кнопкой мыши добавляет дочерний элемент. Нажатие правой - удаляет элемент и все элементы, которые под ним.

Если сделать вот такую штуку, как на скрине
[image: Tree]

А потом удалить точку 2,
то линия, которая идет от 5 к 6 и 7 отрисуется неправильно. Как это можно исправить?

Если на 58 сроке убрать

```
.transition()
.duration(1000)
```

то все будет работать, но без анимации. А нужно, что б анимация осталась.

Или если после 69 строки (где "Пересчет координат линий") добавить `.delay(1000)`, то тоже все будет работать как надо. но анимация получится кривой. Не могу понять, почему оно так работает и как исправить.